AT commands to set LED activity indicators SIM800C not working
I've recently bought a LC SIM800C V3 which is a USB board which looks a bit like this
When plugged in, despite 5V, and connected to network with SIM, I'm not getting any LED activity light show up?
When I run the following:
AT+SLEDS=?

I get an output of:
+SLEDS: (1-3),(0,40-65535),(0,40-65535)

But when then trying to set:
AT+SLED=3,2,2

I get CME error 100
What am I missing?

First, make sure you don't have any typos in your command (AT+SLEDS):
AT+SLEDS=X,X,X

Also, your values are not feasible. You are trying to set LED for 2 milli seconds on and off (second and third arguments) while the module is in PPP mode. (Please refer to the SIM800 document for more info.)
These are the default value:
AT+SLEDS?
+SLEDS: 1,64,800 ### mode=1 means not registered in the network###
+SLEDS: 2,64,3000 ### mode=2 means registered in the network###
+SLEDS: 3,64,300 ### mode=3 means the module is in PPP communication ###

